# Where default protocol is configured for rails `link_to`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Rails `link_to` generates a link with `http://` prfeix. But site is `https`.

So forms must not be used like so. And actually it is not working for most browsers.

The problem appears in `spree` shop. Internal templates of `spree` generates wrong urls. So modify `spree` internal templates to add protocol to each `link_to` is not a solution.

Where default protocol is configured for rails `link_to`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `:protocol => 'https'` inside the url creation.

```
<%= link_to "text", your_url(:protocol => "https"), :method => :post %>
```